# Paypal Payout Api: Client Authentication Failed

Tags: php, laravel, api, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to use the Paypal Payouts API for my laravel webshop. While using sandbox everything worked fine but now that I switched to "live" the error `{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}`   appears. During my research on I found out the issue could be that the application is still in sandbox mode. However, I didn't find how to change the mode. Maybe it could also be a different problem.

Here is my code:

```
 $body= json_decode(
                            '{
                                "sender_batch_header":
                                {
                                  "email_subject": "payout"
                                },
                                "items": [
                                {
                                  "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
                                  "receiver": "'.$email.'",
                                  "note": "Your payout",
                                  "sender_item_id": "payout",
                                  "amount":
                                  {
                                    "currency": "'.$currency.'",
                                    "value": "'.$amount.'" 
                                  }
                                }]
                              }',        
                            true);
                $request2 = new PayoutsPostRequest();
                $request2->body = $body;
                $client = PayPalClient::client();
                $response2 = $client->execute($request2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Client authentication failed indicates one of two things:

1. The client_id and secret are incorrect
2. The client_id and secret are for a different environment (sandbox or live) than the one you are attempting to process with

If you did not change from sandbox credentials to live credentials, and only changed from the sandbox environment to the live environment, this completely explains the error.

Obtain a live client id and secret from an App in the "Live" tab of: https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications